# Have dockerfile overwrite a file in a volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which contains:

```
COPY config.xml /path/to/data/config.xml
```

And when I run the container, I use a volume which itself contains a `config.xml` file

```
volume:
   - "/data:/path/to/data
```

When I build and run the container, I want to `config.xml` from the Image to take priority (and overwrite) the copy that may already exist in the mounted volume.

Is this possible?

Comment: Broadly, no. However you could run a command to copy the file from another location in the image into position at run time (which would overwrite the file in the volume).

Answer (score 4):

When you add a volume to your Docker services, the data in the volume will overwrite any existent data from the Docker image. If you want to have Docker image files that can be used as default files, you need to do the following

- Store the files in the Docker image predefined file ie. (/path/to/default)
- Add an entry point to your Docker file, this entry point should take care of copying the default file from `/path/to/default` to the volume path `/path/to/data`

Dockerfile

```
From ruby:2.4.5
COPY config.xml /path/to/default/config.xml
ENTRYPOINT  [ "/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh -e

cp -r /path/to/default/config.xml /path/to/data
exec "$@" # or replace this by the command need to run the container
```